# How to search by properties of an index

Tags: algolia

I have to retrieve a list of users that consumes an app with a particular ID:

```
const users = algoliaClient.initIndex('users')
return users.search('myId123', { hitsPerPage: 50 });
```

But the users objects are just like this:

```
{apps: [
    {id: 'myId123'},
    {id: 'anotherId456'},
    {id: 'anotherId789'},
]}
```

How can I search the index for items with an apps property that contains an object with such Id?

Answer (score 0):

If you add a period between the attribute and the sub-objects attribute name, you can add this to the 'Searchable Attributes' configuration value to allow it to be searchable. For example, if I wanted the `id` attribute from the array of the `apps` attribute to be searchable, I would configure it like so:

[image: Searchable Attributes example]